# Configure kibana with SSL

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-opendistro

I want to configure Kibana, so, that I can access over `https`.

I did following changes in Kibana config file (/etc/kibana/kibana.yml):

```
server.host: 0.0.0.0
server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.key: /etc/elasticsearch/privkey.pem // Using same SSL that I created for elasticsearch
server.ssl.certificate: /etc/elasticsearch/cert.pem // Using same SSL that I created for elasticsearch

elasticsearch.url: https://127.0.0.1:9200
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
elasticsearch.username: kibanaserver
elasticsearch.password: kibanaserver
elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: ["securitytenant","Authorization"]

opendistro_security.multitenancy.enabled: true
opendistro_security.multitenancy.tenants.preferred: ["Private", "Global"]
opendistro_security.readonly_mode.roles: ["kibana_read_only"]
```

When I restart/start Kibana, it's giving me below error:

```
● kibana.service - Kibana
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kibana.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Wed 2019-06-05 14:20:12 UTC; 382ms ago
      Process: 32505 ExecStart=/usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana -c /etc/kibana/kibana.yml (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 32505 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 05 14:20:11 mts-elk-test systemd[1]: kibana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 05 14:20:11 mts-elk-test systemd[1]: kibana.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 05 14:20:11 mts-elk-test systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 05 14:20:12 mts-elk-test systemd[1]: kibana.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 05 14:20:12 mts-elk-test systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Jun 05 14:20:12 mts-elk-test systemd[1]: kibana.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 05 14:20:12 mts-elk-test systemd[1]: Failed to start Kibana.
Jun 05 14:20:12 mts-elk-test systemd[1]: kibana.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 05 14:20:12 mts-elk-test systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
root@mts-elk-test:/home/ronak# vi /etc/kibana/kibana.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. There was a problem with file permission.
I copied `cert.pem` and `privkey.pem` files from elasticsearch directory to kibana and changed owner with kibana user:

```
chown kibana:kibana /etc/kibana/cert.pem
chown kibana:kibana /etc/kibana/privkey.pem
```

Changed path in `kibana.yml` file:

```
server.ssl.key: /etc/kibana/privkey.pem
server.ssl.certificate: /etc/kibana/cert.pem
```

Rstart kibana: `service kibana restart`

And it worked!